How do I combine several Google Sheets into one using the formula?
In my work I do product pricing with purchase price, minimum price to sell, etc. Each producer has a file on Google's shared drive. The files contain several sheets.
I need some way to quickly and simply merge sheets from several files into one sheet, but so that the content changes depending on what is in the source producer file.
I need this to be able to use the comparison formula in Google Sheet
=JEŻELI.BŁĄD(INDEKS('ExportMT31.05.24'!$S$2:$S$4376;PODAJ.POZYCJĘ($A2;'ExportMT31.05.24'!$K$2:$K$4376;0));"Empty")

I tried this formula:
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*here the sequence of digits and numbers to the file*/edit?usp=sharing";"A1:R999")

But it has two drawbacks
The first is that the formula takes the first sheet from the file, and I usually need the second sheet and can't select it (I copy the link while in the right sheet).
And the other is that I don't know how to add another file to the formula. I would need the formula to allow me to add several file addresses. The final effect would be that the last line of one file would be followed by the contents of the 2nd line of the next file.
In a nutshell... I need a multifile that will update itself according to changes made to other files.
Is this even possible?

Ded you tried the this formula: FILTER + IMPORTRANGE?
If not please try this, it may help you:
{FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("{spreadsheet-ID}", "{sheet#1-name}!{ sheet#1-range}"),LEN(IMPORTRANGE("{spreadsheet-ID}", "{sheet#1-name}!{

